# Convert each row of a dataframe to string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to generate hash code for dataframe using `hashlib.md5` in pyspark. It *only* accepts a string to generate hash code.

I need to convert each row of a dataframe to string.

I tried `concat_ws` function to concatenate all columns and make it as a string but no result.

My dataframe has columns of `Id, name, marks`

**I tried:**

```
str=df.select(concat_ws("id","name","marks"))

print(hashlib.md5(str.encode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict')).hexdigest())
```

**I got this error:**

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: Why don't you use `md5` Spark standard function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try

```
df.select("colname").rdd.map(lambda x: hashlib.md5(str(x).encode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict')).hexdigest()).collect()
```

you should see something like

```
['1dd55a7d40667d697743612f826b71e1', '64a537f89bd95f34374b619452b1a5ab']
```

In your case,

```
df.select(expr("concat_ws(id,name,marks)").alias("mycolumn")).rdd.map(lambda x: hashlib.md5(str(x).encode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict')).hexdigest()).collect()
```